# Trouble with str.replace

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

This is the issue that I am experiencing.

The original column in the dataframe contains insurance names that are like this `"(Do Not Use) Healthfirst"`, and the name of this column is `"InsuranceNames"`. I am using the following code to attempt to sub the `"(Do Not  Use) "` part with a blank and just leave the insurance name:

```
df["InsuranceNames"] = df["InsuranceNames"].str.replace('(Do Not Use)  ','',regex=True)
```

but when I export this to csv the "Do Not Use" is still there. Why is this happening? Some help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use list comprehension  
    df["InsuranceNames"]= [string.replace('(Do not use) ', '') for string in df["InsuranceNames"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have one of two issues or both.

1. When you are looking for an exact string match you shouldn't use regex, so you can drop `regex=True`.
2. You could be wrong on the spacing within `'(Do Not Use) '`. As long `'(Do Not Use) '` is not between to words in the string you will get more reliable results replacing `'(Do Not Use)'` without the space and then using `.strip()` to remove extra spaces from the ends of the string.

Try this:

```
df["InsuranceNames"]=df["InsuranceNames"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('(Do Not Use)','').strip())
```

**Example:**

---

Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"InsuranceNames":['(Do Not Use) Healthfirst', '(Do Not Use) Foobar','  (Do Not Use) Aflac','(Do Not Use)  Foo  ', '(Do Not Use)     Bar']})
```

df:

```
    InsuranceNames
0   (Do Not Use) Healthfirst
1   (Do Not Use) Foobar
2   (Do Not Use) Aflac
3   (Do Not Use) Foo
4   (Do Not Use) Bar
```

Apply:

```
df["InsuranceNames"]=df["InsuranceNames"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('(Do Not Use)','').strip())
```

Output df:

```
    InsuranceNames
0   Healthfirst
1   Foobar
2   Aflac
3   Foo
4   Bar
```

Comment: This suggestion worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help @Bob. Also, I see your question has been closed due to a need for details. If you edit your question to add a sample data frame like I have in this answer, it would likely help to get your question un-closed.